Do we have to invent [p-vs-np] tag? Can we use existing tags for this question?
This question from an active member used a new tag that's never (for as long as I have been a member) seen before: p-vs-np.
Considering the tag is about a long-standing open problem that's yet beyond the reach of human wisdom, I was tempted to re-tag the question with hardness-assumption and complexity. But doing so could invalidate the intent of the OP, so I'd like to ask:
Is re-tagging this particular question an appropriate thing to do?

p-vs-np is too special for this site. Complexity is better,

Tags should be as specific as possible. In that sense this tag is OK. However, there is a thing as too specific. First of all, I don't think we'll see many questions on this topic.
Second, I don't think that this tag will be easily found using either searches or by authors of questions about this particular topic, and it won't gain many followers. As the user did not create / propose a tag wiki I don't think there is much reason to keep the tag. If a tag wiki was created and the tag had a bit more going for it then just adding the tags would be a good option.
